# Page numbering restarts when I changed the orientation of the page - Microsoft Office

Tags: ms-word, orientation

**Problem**

- I am currently writing a report in Microsoft Word 2010.
- I have page numbering at the bottom right of my page, this links to my content page as well.
- Half way through the report I changed the orientation of a few pages to landscape in order to fit some tables and images on them.
- When I changed the orientation the page numbering restarted and I do not want this to happen, I just want it to carry on as normal.
- (I used a 'section break - Next Page' then changed the orientation of the next page; this is on the 'page layout' tab of Microsoft Word 2010.

Any advice?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not programming

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Fixed**

1. Add the same style page numbering on the new orientated page.
2. Right click the page number.
3. Click Format Numbering
4. Click continue from previous page.